# Handle UI Automation Mouse and Keyboard events

Tags: ui-automation

Is it possible to capture mouse and keyboard events of any application using UI Automation?

I am trying to create a UI Automation client application that handles UI Automation events like Focus Change,Menu opened,Menu closed etc.(UIA_ToolTipOpenedEventId,UIA_ToolTipClosedEventId,UIA_MenuOpenedEventId etc.)

When such events occur on any target applications , my test application is able to receive these events. However, i am unable to capture any mouse or keyboard event.

Any help will be appreciated.

Reference link: https://www.universalthread.com/ViewPageArticle.aspx?ID=199 (I am referring to method explained in this article. )

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

Probably global Windows hooks are useful.
See [the MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468841%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for native C++.
There are also Python bindings [pyHook](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyhook/) (64-bit package can be found [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyhook)) that I successfully used for native GUI.
For .NET code probably [WinEvents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd373889%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) reference will be more useful.

When event is captured, you can get handle or mouse coordinates and use something like ElementFromPoint or ElementFromHandle functions from UI Automation API.

Comment: Thanks.But due to limitations, we cannot use any hooks.Hooks definitely solve the purpose.However, we need to use UIAutomation API and UIAutomation interfaces only to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's an old question, I couldn't stop to urge to add an answer here.

No, it's not possible to capture any mouse or keyboard events through UI Automation. You are already getting the UI Events, and I believe your best bet would be to check the mouse position when those events fire, but that's probably not good enough for your scenario. Summary, UI Automation can't help you here.